# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight-5.0

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="DataSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_GetData">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost/MyApp.Web/Webservice/Data.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DataSoap"
            contract="ServiceReference1.DataSoap" name="DataSoap" />

        <endpoint address="https://localhost/MyApp.Web/Webservice/GetData.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_GetData"
            contract="GetData.GetData" name="CustomBinding_GetData" />           
    </client>        
</system.serviceModel>
```

Hello every one, above is my silverlight applications ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file. The site is configured to be accessed over https. From the above file, i would imagine i have everything configured correctly. I can browser to my service from local development environment successfully but after deploying the application in my QA environment, browing to the service gives me the error below.

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding CustomBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Any i dea why http is still being picked as the registered base address schemes only QA but not in my local development environment?.

**EDIT:**
@Brian, thanks for the reply, let me give you more information just in case it gives a much clear picture.

The site is configured for SSL, but the SSL certificate is installed on a load balancer which i have no access to. 
Now from the error message, it would seem like i have to configure Host Headers and Secure Site Bindings in IIS, but can i really do this from IIS when the SSL certificate is installed and managed from the load balancer?

IT looks like the https binding are what is missing because i can reproduce the exact same error message from my development machine if i temporarily remove the https binding i created following this link.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.

So would i be right to think that i need that https binding on the load balancer rather than in IIS because the site has no SSL certificate of its own in IIS?

Comment: OK, so it's what I thought. You are not going to fix this changing the IIS settings. The cert's on the LB. You either fix the cert on the LB so that it matches the DNS of the web service (server side fix), or you fix it on the client side with the change I recommended in my answer: using code on the client side to override the certificate DNS so it always matches the URL of the web service.

Comment: I am not understanding how i would make the certificate DNS matche the DNS of the web service because the web service is hosted in the application. Is it possible to get this resolved by tweaking the web service configuration?

Comment: Making the cert DNS match the web service DNS is done when the certificate is generated.

Comment: Making the cert DNS match the web service DNS is done when the certificate is generated. Let's say your public web service address is: https://XYZCorp:9001/MyEndpoint ... in other words, that's the public URL to which your clients point their programs. The DNS setting inside the cert needs to match "XYZCorp", otherwise the certificate check that the client side automatically does will fail. Your LB guys may have used "LoadBalancer01" as the DNS/URL when the certificate was generated. The way to check would be to poach a copy of the cert then look at the details.

Comment: To be more specific, the cert "subject" field needs to match the DNS or IP that the client application.  See my edit below

Comment: Many thanks @Brian, looks like we getting closer to the solution. Looking at the certificate, i see it was issued to qa-https://server1.section1.myDomain.org but the load balancer guys gave me a different URL for testing the SSL config which is actaully by IP but not the DNS name that the certificate was issued to. So currently connections to https://qa-server1.section1.myDomain.org are not yet https enabled. So do you think if the DNS is updated such that access can be by https://qa-server1.section1.myDomain.org that can solve the problem?

Comment: yes, that should resolve the problem. As long as the URL you're using to access the LB (which acts as a proxy for you web service) and the URL on the certificate match, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem. Basically, the URL identity associated with the certificate doesn't match the URL of the website from which it comes ... at least that was my problem.

I was able to work around this client-side security check by specifically setting (in code) the System.ServiceModel.EndPointIdentity to the URL I was connecting to.

There's a CreateDNSIdentity() function to which you give the URL of the website you're hitting.

Here's a link to the MS documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointidentity.creatednsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm not sure how you'd configure this without using code.

```
String sFullURL = "http://MyDNSServer:8001/SomeService"
String sDNS = "MyDNSServer";
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress Endpoint;
System.ServiceModel.EndpointIdentity Identity = default (System.ServiceModel.EndpointIdentity);
Identity = System.ServiceModel.EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(sDNS);
EndPoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(sFullURL), Identity);
```

**UPDATE**
OK, so imagine you had a web service and the public address for this web service was IP https:// 10.134.116.161:8001/MyService. The certificate below would pass the client-side cert verification check and you would not get an error. But if this certificate shown in the picture below is deployed on public URL https:// XZYCorp:8001/MyService, you'll get that error. So you either need to override the client side cert verification check or change the cert on the LB.

[image]

Comment: I have given more information but it was too long for a comment here, so i added it as an edit to my original post, check it out.

Comment: in my case, the subject line you have highlighted above shows the public URL qa-server1.section1.myDomain.org but i am getting the error while accessing the web service via IP. Does mean i ask the load balancer guys to instead update the DNS such that i directly use qa-server1.section1.myDomain.org NOT the IP, the problem would be resolved?

Comment: Why not hit the web service using the "MyDomain" URL instead of the IP address? I would think that's the easiest thing to do.